# How update my Sqlite for Android in 8 String?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

How update my Sqlite for Android in 8 String?

```
  if (videoBool==0 || audioBool==0){
        DBHelper dbHelper=new DBHelper(this);
        SQLiteDatabase database= dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("indexAuthor",indexAuthor);
        contentValues.put("indexPoetry",indexPoetry);
        contentValues.put("videoBool",videoBool);
        contentValues.put("audioBool",audioBool);
        database.update("MediaBool",contentValues,position,null);
        dbHelper.close();
    }
```

I need to update a row in the table which is on the 8th position

Comment: You should create a update method in `DBHelper` How you are putting values should be defined there

Comment: If you have an "_ID" column in your table, just use the update query with a where clause as " _ID=8". Use content values to update the ro.

Comment: @AtishAgrawal, on id will not go.
how should the code look? please you answer in code

     database.update("MediaBool",contentValues,5,null);?

Comment: try re writing the question to explain your actual need. Why are you interested in 8th row?